# web.xml web-resource-name not optional

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml

Recently I added authorization to our JEE application and to achieve this, I added the following lines to our `web.xml`:

## web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER_LOGIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But on validating the file, my IDE responds that it expects a `web-resource-name` before specifying the URLs to secure:

## web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER_LOGIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And a cross-reference to the respective XML schema underlines this assumption:

## web-common_3_1.xsd

```
<xsd:complexType name="web-resource-collectionType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>

            The web-resource-collectionType is used to identify the
            resources and HTTP methods on those resources to which a
            security constraint applies. If no HTTP methods are specified,
            then the security constraint applies to all HTTP methods.
            If HTTP methods are specified by http-method-omission
            elements, the security constraint applies to all methods
            except those identified in the collection.
            http-method-omission and http-method elements are never
            mixed in the same collection. 

            Used in: security-constraint

        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="web-resource-name" type="javaee:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>

                    The web-resource-name contains the name of this web
                    resource collection.

                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
```

So, besides setting it to an alibi-name, what is the use of it and why does Oracle describes it as

> web-resource-name is the name you use for this resource. Its use is optional.

when the XML schema clearly states that it is mandatory?

Comment: I don't know what it's purpose is or why it's mandatory either, but both WebSphere and WildFly accept it not being there without any errors or warnings.